# SignUp Form Validation: Frontend Javascript versus backend Python?

Tags: javascript, python, web-applications, web, client-server

Client side Javascript versus Server Side Python

If I want to create a registration form, what are the pros and cons of validating - checking - for incorrect input- through each method. What do you recommend?

Comment: I mean more for validation and checking if input is correct

Comment: From [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aYVFBnurpNY): "let's take all the security, and put it on the client side, i.e. let's just give it to the hacker". You NEED server side validation at the very least

Comment: The two answers you have so far should get you started (at the very least) and supersede anything that I can say on the matter. I was answering your question in a very basic way, which is why it was a comment and not a full answer. Also, which campus are you at?

Comment: @RohitRayudu: The next time you ask a question here please write it in a way that does not make it look subjective. This especially involves **not** including phrases such as "what do you recommend?"

Comment: How would u rephrase that? I be liking to hear different peoples opinions? Subjectivity should be encouraged, so that we can hear all the voices in this planet we be calling Earth.

Comment: Stack Overflow is not a place to ask subjective questions! http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask

Comment: Then how will you ever know the meaning of life? There is no such thing as 1 correct answer. LOL - StackOverflow must still be living in the world of Grade 3 where 2 plus 2 be equaling 4.

Comment: As stated in the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#dontask), *Please avoid chatty, open-ended questions.* If you want to use Stack Overflow , that is a constraint that you're going to have to come to terms with.

Comment: It is time to revolutionize StackOverflow then!! Prepare for some competition.

Comment: Does that mean you are moving to experts exchange? :)

Comment: Sh....Don't tell anyone. (It's a secret.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**JavaScript**
 - Pros:
Easy to test and implement. When doing form validation JavaScript can do instantaneous validation and has many utilities for regex checking and DOM traversal (jQuery). Also, the processing is offloaded to the client (though this may be negligible).
 - Cons:
Users that don't support JavaScript

**Python**
 - Pros:
Support for users without JavaScript. Hidden and therefore more secure.
 - Cons:
The page will need to be refreshed in order for results to be displayed. This may be frustrating for some users as not all fields (eg password field) should be saved.

I would use JavaScript for instantaneous feedback and Python for end-result error-checking and as a fallback for users without JavaScript.

Comment: Thank You Bustin Jieber Fumpord!

Answer (score 9):

You **need** server-side (backend) code to create a signup system. You need to somehow create the user and store the data entered by the user after all and that cannot be done on the client.

The most common case to mix server-side and client-side is like this:

- Use client-side code to improve the user experience. This means: Initial validation, possibly AJAX requests to check if e.g. the chosen username is valid and available.
- Use server-side code for the final validation (you cannot trust *anything* coming from the client) and obviously to eventually perform the actual signup by creating a new user and storing it in your database.

Assuming that the vast majority of your users have JavaScript enabled and you do not bother providing a great UX to those who don't, too, you *could* simplify things by providing detailed error messages (e.g. involving highlighting of the erroneous fields) in your client-side validation logic while just displaying a generic error message if something fails the server-side validation.
However, in case there are things you cannot properly validate on the client (even though that's unlikely in case he has JS enabled since you can then use AJAX), you should make sure that the server-side validation does show a proper error message so the user knows what's wrong.

If the user does not submit anything huge (such as file uploads) and you have some clean way to re-fill all form fields in case of an invalid submission the easiest solution would be doing only server-side validation as this would avoid creating validation logic twice (assuming you do not have some way to specify it in an abstract way that can be accessed by both server-side and client-side code).

Another possibility - especially a good idea when password fields are involved (for good UX you want to preserve what the user entered even after a bad submission but from a security point of view you should not send the user's password back to avoid it from being cached somewhere) - would be using AJAX to submit the whole form and e.g. send back a JSON payload containing the URL where the user should be redirected in case of success or a list of errors in case of failure. This especially has the advantage that you could easily write your server-side code in a way that either returns the JSON payload in case of an AJAX request or a full HTML page in case of a normal request.

Comment: Do you think it is worth it to do a mixture of both or does doing everything through server side code significantly increase the time taken to submit and process the form?

Comment: Yes, it is worth it to do a mixture of both. If there is a problem the user has to wait for the response to come back, where client side validation can often pick issues up immediately.

Comment: In security wise, it's always necessary to validate the data coming from front end, as your form could be XHR attacked. 

In user experience wise, a front end validation would save users time from waiting a response from the backend, plus with a good JS UI Framework (e.g. ExtJS, jQuery UI) will help spruce up your forms.